# Cannot read property subscribe and error context

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb

I want my program to show an image (or several, I don´t care).
I put spaces on tags so you could see them, it's not in the code.
// I have the list component where I show my images, and the upload component where I show my list and upload my images to be saved on the list.

// This is my List.Component.html (it doesn't shows the images)

```
< div class="col-12"><br>
  < div class="row"><br>
    < div *ngFor="let a of myImages"><br>
      < img class="img-fluid img-thumbnail image" src="{{a.fileUrl}}" alt="imagen"/><br>
      < span>{{a.fileName}}</ span><br>
    </ div><br>
  </ div><br>
</ div>
```

//  This is my  List.Components.ts where I have the method to list my images.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';<br>
import {UploadService} from '../../services/upload.service';<br>

@Component({
  selector: 'app-list',
  templateUrl: './list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./list.component.css']
})<br>
export class ListComponent implements OnInit {<br>

myImages;<br>

  constructor(private uploadService : UploadService) { }<br>

  ngOnInit() {<br>
    this.getImages();<br>
  }


  getImages(){<br>
    this.uploadService.getImages().subscribe(data=>{<br>
      console.log('los datos de las imagenes: ', data)<br>
      this.myImages = data;<br>
    })
  }
}

// Then this is my UploadComponent.html where I call my ListComponent and there is my onFileChange method that gives me the error, one of them.

< div class="input-file-form"><br>
    < div class="card"><br>
      < div class="card-body p-4"><br>
        < h4>Subida de imagenes o archivos</h4><br>

        < div class="card"><br>
            < div class="card-body p-4"><br>
              < app-list></app-list><br>
          </ div><br>
        </ div><br>

  < form [formGroup] = "imageForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()"><br>
    < div class="col-md-20"><br>
      < input  class="form-control" type="file" placeholder="File" (change)="onFileChange($event)" formControlName="file"><br>
  
      < img *ngIf="image" class="img-fluid img-thumbnail image" src="{{image}}"><br>
    </ div><br>
  
    < input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Name" formControlName="name"><br>
  
    < br><br>
  
    < button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-lg btn-block" [disabled]="!imageForm.valid">Enviar< /button><br>
    

  </ form><br>
  </ div><br>
  </ div><br>
  </div><br>
```

// AND this is my Upload.Component.ts where I implement my onFileChange method. My error says that I can't 'subscribe' and don't know how that's happening.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';<br>

import {FormControl, Validators,FormGroup, NgForm} from '@angular/forms';<br>

import {UploadService} from '../../services/upload.service';<br>

@Component({
  selector: 'app-upload',
  templateUrl: './upload.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./upload.component.css']
})<br>
export class UploadComponent implements OnInit {<br>

  imageForm : FormGroup;<br>
  image: any ="../../../assets/homepage.jpg";<br>
  file: any;<br>
  constructor(private uploadService : UploadService) { }<br>

  ngOnInit() {<br>
    this.imageForm = new FormGroup({<br>
      name: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),<br>
      file: new FormControl(null, Validators.required)<br>
    });
  }

onFileChange(event){<br>
  //no entra en el if

  if (event.target.files && event.target.files.length>0) {<br>
    const file = event.target.files[0];<br>
    if (file.type.includes("image")) {<br>
      const reader = new FileReader();<br>
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);<br>
      reader.onload = function load(){<br>
        this.image = reader.result;<br>
      }.bind(this);<br>
      this.file=file;<br>
    }else{<br>
      console.log('there was an error')<br>
    }
    }
  }



onSubmit(){<br>

  const form = this.imageForm;<br>
  if (form.valid) {<br>
    console.log('sdkf', form)<br>
    this.uploadService.uploadImage(form.value.name, this.file).subscribe(data=>{<br>
      this.imageForm = new FormGroup({<br>
        name: new FormControl(null,Validators.required),<br>
        file: new FormControl(null, Validators.required)<br>
      });
      this.image = "../../../assets/homepage.jpg";<br>
      console.log(this.imageForm);<br>
      console.log(form)<br>
    })
  }

  console.log('uploaded image');
}
}


// My Upload.Service.ts where I call my server and take the data.


import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';<br>
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';<br>
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';<br>


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UploadService {<br>

server = "http://localhost:3000"<br>

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }<br>



  getImages(){<br>
    return this.http.get(`${this.server}/download`)<br>
  }

  uploadImage(name:string, file:File){<br>
    if (name!=null && file !=null) {<br>
      
    const form = new FormData()<br>
    form.append('name', name);<br>
    form.append('file', file, 'form-data');<br>

    return this.http.post<Object>(`${this.server}/upload`, form);<br>
  }}
}
```

// My backend with mongodb works pretty good, it saves the images and it shows me the data on console.log.

//  The class that make the posts and gets on backend

```
----------------------------------uploadImage.js--------------------------------------------

'use strict'

const router = require('express').Router();<br>
const Image = require('../models/Image');<br>
const storage = require('../../config/multer');<br>
const multer = require('multer');<br>


const uploader = multer({<br>
    storage 
}).single('file');<br>

router.post('/upload', uploader, async (req, res)=>{<br>
    const { body, file } = req<br>
    if(file && body){<br>
        const newImage = new Image({<br>
            fileName : body.fileName,<br>
            fileUrl: `http://localhost:3000/${file.filename}`<br>
        })
        await newImage.save();<br>
        res.json({<br>
            newImage : newImage<br>
        })
    }
})

router.get('*',async (req,res)=>{<br>
const images = await Image.find();<br>
res.json(images);<br>
})
module.exports = router;<br>
```

//  I GET THIS ERROR and don't know how to fix it: It go inside my else on my onFileChange() method and says 'there was an error'

[what it returns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uyWUf.jpg)

[my errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rmn4p.jpg)

Comment: in your upload service you didn't consider the case where if condition is false. in that case , are you returning an observable ?

Comment: No, I'm not returning an observable on my upload service, should i? :(

Comment: if you are not returning an observable then what are you subscribing in component ? You should

Comment: I don't really know how to do that, I'll keep looking. Thanks!

Comment: remove if condition from your service because you already checked form validation in your component function onSubmit

Comment: I did that and I received these errors :-> [WDS] Errors while compiling. Reload prevented.
-> src/app/services/upload.service.ts(33,1): error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.  I also tried to remove the if from onsubmit and same error of subscribe property